# android - signature version is not in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, signed-apk

I want to get signed version of my android app but there is no Signature versions in the wizard. what is going on? how can I achieve that?

[image]

I do not have those below

[image]

my android studio is like that

Comment: Try this: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: can you clarify what you want to ask. It is completely unclear now

Comment: I want those options. I have some problem in updating my app and think those are my solutions

Comment: What options you want? i guess you want flavors options? right?

Comment: See this link and you got your answer. you need to change your build.gradle file: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: not flavers @AndyDeveloper , I want signature version , v1 and v2

Comment: You need to update your studio version. you are running old version try to update your studio and its done. :)

Comment: realy?? my AS is 2.2.2 . just update it?

Comment: yes really. try update your studio and its done.

Comment: ok , I try it. thankd @AndyDeveloper

Comment: `APK Signature Scheme v2` will be available in `Android Studio 2.3.0` onward